# Amplitude of graph clips when magnified

Tags: matlab, plot

This is the code for plotting I am using

```
 figure
 x = -pi:pi/40:pi;
 plot(x,cos(5*x),'-ro',x,sin(5*x),'-.b')
 hleg1 = legend('cos_x','sin_x');
```

The output comes like this:

[image]

When I try to stretch the time axis, what I get is like this:

[image]

But as can be seen, the amplitude gets clipped when I stretch the time axis. How do I avoid this clipping of amplitude when stretching time axis and v.V?

Comment: What do you mean by "stretch"?

Comment: Have you tried: While zooming, right-click -> zoom options -> Horizontal zoom

Comment: stretch means magnifying

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try using "Zoom In," the plus-magnifying glass icon and being very careful to select the entire vertical range of the image. To control the minimum and maximum values of the axes more precisely using the `axis` function.

```
 figure
 x = -pi:pi/40:pi;
 plot(x,cos(5*x),'-ro',x,sin(5*x),'-.b')
 hleg1 = legend('cos_x','sin_x');
 axis([1.6, 3.2,-1, 1])
```